# Talking to SQL Integration Services with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I want to import and export SSIS packages (.DTSX files) on a SQL Server with a C# program. I found information on an "Integration Services" class, but I'm not seeing any methods related to exporting or importing packages. Is this the correct class? If not, where should I be looking?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.integrationservices?view=sqlserver-2017

`public ref class IntegrationServices`

Comment: Not my downvote but I am sure it because like me, that person doesn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @SeanLange I want to be able to export and import SQL Server Integration Services packages (SSIS) in a C# program. I'm sure Microsoft has classes I can use to do so, but I can't seem to find them. I provided a link of where I think the documentation should be, but I'm not seeing it there.

Comment: The downvote is probably because there's no clear error provided.  You're asking a general "help" question which is not the true purpose here (I've done it too).  Some one will undoubtedly offer you a tidbit to go off of though...

Comment: Perhaps the [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2017) class?

Comment: @DaveCullum I suppose I could retool the question to showing errors for where that class didn't work for me, but that would be a waste of everyone's time as I've already determined that it's not the correct class to use!

Comment: @SMor That looks promising! I'm going to do some digging in that class. Thank you!

Comment: If all else fails, programmatically invoking [`dtutil`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility) is one way. The managed classes have a tendency of being slow, poorly documented, functionally incomplete or an uncomfortable combination of these.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Funny you should mention that, I actually wrote a fully functioning C# program using dtutil as the engine driving the SSIS imports and exports. The utility needs to do a bunch of other things now, so I want to "clean it up" and use the legitimate C# stuff rather than calling command line utilities.

Comment: If you're not already using it, I've seen people use [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell) to invoke command line tools as well (even when no PowerShell scripts are involved); it has a nicer interface for pipelining commands, adding arguments and processing output. You could almost forget that tools are being invoked this way. :-) The "legitimate C# stuff" is nice -- when it works. If you do get it to work to your satisfaction, be sure to write up an answer.

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? SSIS Catalog or legacy SQL/MSDB package store?

Comment: @Ferdipux I think SQL/MSDB package store. Basing this on seeing an "MSDB" folder when you login to Integration Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be what user @SMor suggested, the Application class of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/enumerating-available-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017

These two objects give you most of what you need:

`Application ssisApplication;

PackageInfos sqlPackages;`

I can get the list of packages with that class. Now I'm just working on how to actually do the imports/exports.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for Package export from SQL to File.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

public void pkgExtract() 
{
  // ...
  Application app = new Application();
  var events = new PackageEvents();
  Package package = app.LoadFromSqlServer(packageName, server, etl.UserName, etl.Password, events);
  // ...
  string Package_File = @"C:\\Temp\ExportPkg.dtsx"
  app.SaveToXml(Package_File, package, null);

}
```

For reverse directrion - you can use `LoadPackage` and `SaveToSQLServer` methods.